# multiple models in one view models connecting class

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I'm trying to figure out how can I implement 2 models in one view for the last 2-3 days. I made a topic on it, but when I tried to implement it, the code just didn't work, I got a lot of errors and when I finally got the website running, I got InvalidOperationException error.
My model in the index view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Hotel_Reservations_Manager.Models.Models>
```

Here is my Index view page:

```
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Reservations.RoomId)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Reservations.isAllInclusive)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Reservations.Price)
                </th>
                <th>Control</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach (var itemz in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @itemz.Reservations.RoomId
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @itemz.Reservations.isAllInclusive
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @itemz.Reservations.Price
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@itemz.Reservations.ID"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:24px;"></i></a>
                        <form id="delform" method="post" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@itemz.Reservations.ID">
                            <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@itemz.Reservations.ID" onclick="DelFunc();"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" style="font-size:24px;color:red"></i></a>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
```

Here is the model in the Create View:

```
@model Hotel_Reservations_Manager.Models.Models
```

Here is the Create View:

```
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Reservations.RoomId" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Reservations.RoomId" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Reservations.RoomId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="Reservations.isAllInclusive" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Reservations.isAllInclusive)
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Reservations.Price" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Reservations.Price" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Reservations.Price" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input style="width: 6rem;" type="submit" value="Create" class="crt-btn" />
                <a style="width: 6rem; text-decoration: none; color:white;" asp-action="Index" class="crt-btn">Back</a>
            </div>
        </form>
```

The class with my two models:

```
public class Models
{
    public ReservationsModel Reservations { get; set; }
    public RoomsModel Rooms { get; set; }
}
```

My reservations Controller for the Create action (on POST):

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Models.Models model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(model.Reservations);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(model.Reservations);
    }
```

Comment: show constructor with passed in "_context".

Comment: There you go:
private readonly SQLContext _context;

        public ReservationsController(SQLContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

Comment: include that in your post(is that a table? there's no table name in your _context.Add), along with the model(s) for your database context vs "view" model.  Is "Models" class a view model for a specific page?   Also add the exception you receive and when that happens.  (both index and create?)

Comment: I don't have any problems with it, when I use only one of the models (for example the ReservationsModel) everything works perfectly. I'm trying to get the data from the rooms as well. I dont' have problem with the constructor of the controller. And models as I showed above is the class that joins both of my models (the Reservations model and the Rooms model).

Comment: it's hard to know what you are trying to achieve with the code posted since it appears to be for a single reservation, and you are having no problem with it.   Accessing the room data seems like it should be done through a foreign key.  "Model" is kind of a broad word to be using... but it's not clear where the "Model" class is.  Is that in index.cs and create.cs?

Comment: I'll think later what I'll be doing with the Rooms model. At the moment I want to be able to access the Reservations model through the "Models" class. But it seems like my code isn't correct because it doesn't create a new reservation on the POST but I get InvalidOperationException error.

Comment: post the full code for your .cs files.  The constructors/properties will be important... these files will pass the "page model" to your .cshtml files.  I think what you really want is to just add the model you need as a property there.  So public RoomsModel Rooms { get; set; } is a property in your .cs file.  (though you may not need that but only a list of ids...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Create View requires a model item of type `Hotel_Reservations_Manager.Models.Models`, but you return model.Reservations `(a item of type Hotel_Reservations_Manager.Models.ReservationsModel)` to Create view when `ModelState.IsValid` is false, which causes this error.

You can directly reuturn the model in the post action.

```
return View(model);
```

> But it seems like my code isn't correct because it doesn't create a new reservation on the POST

Because the ModelState.IsVaild is false, which means the model didn't pass the validation (such as you didn't give a value for a required property), you should have a check. If you can't still solve it, plesase attach the codes for `ReservationsModel` and `RoomsModel` to your post.

Comment: It seems like that I didn't gave a value to every property. I fixed it now and replaced the return value as you said to "View(model);".
Now everything works, but I still get the error when trying to access the Index page:
InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Hotel_Reservations_Manager.Models.ReservationsModel]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Hotel_Reservations_Manager.Models.Models]'.

Comment: After using directly the "ReservationsModel" instead of "Models" in the Index view everything works perfectly. (I don't need both models in the Index page). Thank you for your response and your time!